# Angular2 cli import error

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design-lite

I am trying to use mdl-stepper in my Angular2 project. 
In my HTML:

```
    <li class="mdl-step">
        <span class="mdl-step__label">
            <span class="mdl-step__title">
                <span class="mdl-step__title-text">Step 2</span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <div class="mdl-step__content">
            <h4>Step 2</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-step__actions">
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-button--raised" data-stepper-next>
                Continue 
            </button>
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-stepper-cancel>
                Cancel
            </button>
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-stepper-back 
            (click)="onstepback($event)">
                Back
            </button>
        </div>
    </li>
```

On back button click I am firing an event. In my `home.component.ts` file inside `onbackstep(){}` I have following:

```
var stepperElement = document.querySelector('ul.mdl-stepper');
var Stepper;

Stepper = stepperElement.MaterialStepper;
```

It gives me compilation error saying `Property 'MaterialStepper' does not exist on type 'Element'`

Do I have to import something?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
var stepperElement = document.querySelector(selector);

Its working for me. There is no error now.

Comment: How do you define selector in your component?

Comment: Perhaps you could answer this latest question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994410/using-mdl-stepper-events-in-angular2-cli