# Using mdl-stepper events in angular2 cli

Tags: angular

I am using mdl-stepper in my angular2 project created through CLI (https://ahlechandre.github.io/mdl-stepper/component/). It is rendered correctly after DOM upgrade. JS and CSS is included in my angular-cli.json:

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/material-design-lite/dist/material.amber-blue.min.css",
    "../node_modules/mdl-stepper/stepper.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/material-design-lite/material.min.js",
    "../node_modules/mdl-stepper/stepper.min.js"

  ],
```

However to implements its methods like next(), back() etc. I am not sure what and how should be imported in my component?

The example shows following:

```
var stepperElement = document.querySelector('.mdl-stepper');
// Get the MaterialStepper instance of element.
var Stepper = stepperElement.MaterialStepper;
// Select any step other than the first (for obvious reasons).
var step = element.querySelector('.mdl-step:nth-child(2)');

step.addEventListener('onstepback', function (event) {
  // When the step (this) action button/link with [data-stepper-back] attribute is clicked
  // you can call the back() method or do anything else.
  Stepper.back();
});
```

Specifiallly `var Stepper = stepperElement.MaterialStepper;` throws me error saying MaterialStepper is undefined.